# Astro: Exclude dependency internal import from turning into an API route

Tags: reactjs, import, url-routing, astrojs

In an [Astro](https://astro.build/) app, I am consuming an (in-house) React component library where the components import their own styling which is expressed in files such as `Foo.css.map` (for the `Foo` component).

As I am using [api routes](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/server-side-rendering/#api-routes), I have files such as `pages/samples/[id].astro`.

But when the library components render within `[id].astro` and perform their own imports, the `[id].astro` file additionally renders with `id` having values like `Foo.css.map`.
**I only want `[id].astro` to be invoked when the requested url ends with `Foo`, not `Foo.css.map`**.

**How can I exclude certain file patterns from turning into API routes?**

Perhaps something to do with how I name the `pages/samples/[id].astro` file?

Comment: Can you share a [link to a reproduction of the problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/astro-u5svtq?file=src%2Fpages%2Fsamples%2F[id].astro&on=stackblitz)?

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Are you trying to optimize network requests, or do you need to obfuscate your source code on the client?